# Haskell - Convert x number of tuples into a list

Tags: list, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add x tuples into a list x number of times? - Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715844/how-do-i-add-x-tuples-into-a-list-x-number-of-times-haskell)

I need to write a function that takes in any number of tuples and convert them into a list. 
**This is an example of how the tuples will look like: `("String1",value1),("String2",value)("String3",value3)`. The number of tuples is depending on how many the user want to input.
The function will then convert it to a list like this: `[("String1",value1),("String2",value2),("String3",value3)]`**

**It's then supposed to return the strings. I know how to return the strings etc but I'm having a trouble on how to make it so the users decide how many tuples they want to add.**

Note: I dont want an entire solution to the whole assignment. I just need help with the bolded text.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7715844/671703)?